# Make several tasks one after the other in a loop

Tags: android, asynchronous, task

I have object array,
I want for each object of this array to create a pdf. To do this I use a loop but the problem is that it creates me the PDF file of the last one.

I think I know why, because the task does not have the time to finish that it continues on the following one.

I would like to stop the loop until the pdf file is created, then resume the next iteration ...

With each iteration I want to stop the loop to give the time to create the pdf file

here is my code:

```
for (i in 0 until multipleInvoice!!.size) {

            receiveUser = MainActivity.users.find { it.codeZ == multipleInvoice!![i].customerCodeZ }
            products = multipleInvoice!![i].retrieveInvoice(this)
            receiveInvoice = multipleInvoice!![i]

            doAsync {
                // Long background task
                progressBar.setVisible()
                htmlContent = renderHTML()

                uiThread {
                    //webViewInitializer(htmlContent)
                    doAsync {
                        htmlToPDF(htmlContent) //Is function create PDF file on the phone!!!
                        //Here I want to stop the loop until the file is created 
                        // (by the function of the line above). As soon as the file is created, we take the loop 
                    }
                    progressBar.setGone()
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use any loop to achieve what you want. There is a way to perform what you want using recursion. When you have multipleInvoice call this function with 0th position to render PDF.

```
if(multipleInvoice?:0 >0)    
  renderInvoice(0)


fun renderInvoice(i:Int) {

        receiveUser = MainActivity.users.find { it.codeZ == multipleInvoice!![i].customerCodeZ }
        products = multipleInvoice!![i].retrieveInvoice(this)
        receiveInvoice = multipleInvoice!![i]

        doAsync {
            // Long background task
            progressBar.setVisible()
            htmlContent = renderHTML()

            uiThread {
                //webViewInitializer(htmlContent)
                doAsync {
                    htmlToPDF(htmlContent) //Is function create PDF file on the phone!!!
                    //Here I want to stop the loop until the file is created 
                    // (by the function of the line above). As soon as the file is created, we take the loop 
                   if(i< multipleInvoice!!.size)
                     renderInvoice(++i)
                }
                progressBar.setGone()
            }
        }
    }
```